# En rimant, est-ce qu'on considère les consonnes spirantes comme une partie de la voyelle ou la consonne au début?

Tags: phonétique, poésie

Est-il essentiel que les sons /j/, /w/, et /ɥ/ (Alphabet phonétique international) dans une rime soient les mêmes ? Par exemple, est-ce que « argüer », « louer », et « nier » riment?

Answer (score 2):

En poésie, la diérèse s'impose pour « louer » et « nier ». Elle atténue ou supprime la consonne spirante et isole nettement la voyelle finale : /lwe/ → /lu.e/, /nje/ → /ni.e/ ou /nij.e/.

Ces trois mots riment donc mais d'une rime pauvre, c'est à dire ne reprenant que la dernière voyelle, ici /e/.

Comment: Est-ce que cette règle s'applique aussi aux mots à plus qu'une syllabe (dénouer, dernier) ?

Comment: Le nombre de syllabes n'intervient pas, l'étymologie si. Quand la racine latine a deux syllabes là où le français n'en a plus qu'une, il y a en général diérèse. « Dénouer » a trois syllabes en poésie (*nodus*). « dernier » en a deux.